# How to get date from time element in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to get date from time element in the [website](https://www.trustpilot.com/review/www.spotify.com) but the result is NA.

```
url <- "https://www.trustpilot.com/review/www.spotify.com"

dates <- read_html(url) %>% 
  html_nodes("div.review-content-header__dates") %>% 
  html_attr("datetime")
```

What's wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No node name such this above!

Comment: Which date do you want? The published date? The nodes you target contain: `<div class="review-content-header__dates"> <script type="application/json" data-initial-state="review-dates"> {"publishedDate":"2019-09-12T08:00:12Z", "updatedDate":null,"reportedDate":null} ...`

Comment: @Chelmy88 the published date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want is the field `publishedDate` inside the `<script>` node you can do:

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.trustpilot.com/review/www.spotify.com"
dates <- read_html(url) %>% 
  html_nodes("div.review-content-header__dates") %>%
  html_text()

# Now do some cleaning on the obtained data
# Remove extra spaces
dates <- gsub('\\s+','',dates)
# Remove text before the date
dates <- gsub('\\{\"publishedDate\":\"','',dates)
# Remove text after the date
dates <- gsub('Z\",\".*','',dates)

dates

 > [1] "2019-09-23T15:02:07" "2019-09-21T15:24:14" "2019-09-20T15:16:35"
 > [4] "2019-09-20T13:45:35" "2019-09-19T14:48:44" "2019-09-18T02:56:34"
 > [7] "2019-09-16T00:24:32" "2019-09-13T00:04:14" "2019-09-12T19:47:27"
 > [10] "2019-09-12T12:59:54" "2019-09-12T08:00:12" "2019-09-11T13:18:01"
 > [13] "2019-09-10T08:07:54" "2019-09-05T16:16:53" "2019-09-05T14:17:42"
 > [16] "2019-09-04T19:49:28" "2019-09-04T18:33:04" "2019-09-02T18:45:53"
 > [19] "2019-08-31T20:53:44" "2019-08-30T23:24:25"
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you wanted to know how to extract the script tag content and parse in as json object then extract a dataframe of reviews (including extracting date part of published date)

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
library(jsonlite)
library(purrr)

r <- jsonlite::parse_json(gsub(';|\\n+','',read_html('https://www.trustpilot.com/review/www.spotify.com') %>%
     html_node('[data-business-unit-json-ld]') %>% html_text()))

df <- map_df(r[[1]]$review, function(item) {

  data.frame( author = item$author$name,
              date = strsplit(item$datePublished,"T")[[1]][1] ,
              headline = item$headline,
              reviewBody = item$reviewBody,
              rating = item$reviewRating$ratingValue,
             stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
})

View(df)
```

Example output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
url <- "https://www.trustpilot.com/review/www.spotify.com"
dates <- read_html(url) %>% 
  html_nodes("div.review-content-header__dates") %>%
  html_text() %>% 
  stringi::stri_trim_both() #here

dates <- gsub('\\{\"publishedDate\":\"','',dates)
dates <- gsub('\\T.*','',dates) #and here
dates
```

You get just the date by code that's little bit different @Chelmy88's above.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to extract dates using `sub`

```
url <- "https://www.trustpilot.com/review/www.spotify.com"
library(rvest)

url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("div.review-content-header__dates") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  sub('.*publishedDate.*(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}).*', '\\1', .)

# [1] "2019-09-23" "2019-09-21" "2019-09-20" "2019-09-20" "2019-09-19" "2019-09-18" "2019-09-16"
# [8] "2019-09-13" "2019-09-12" "2019-09-12" "2019-09-12" "2019-09-11" "2019-09-10" "2019-09-05"
#[15] "2019-09-05" "2019-09-04" "2019-09-04" "2019-09-02" "2019-08-31" "2019-08-30"
```